# How to improve nested conditionals

Tags: ruby

Could you please help me on improving these piece of code?

```
def print_last_frame(result, frame, i)
    line = ''
    if frame.strike?
      if frame.result.reduce(:+) == 30
        line += "X\t X\t X"
      elsif frame.result.reduce(:+) == 20
        line += "X\t #{frame.result[1]}\t /"
      else
        line += "X\t #{frame.result[1]}\t #{frame.result[2]}"
      end
    elsif frame.spare?
      if frame.result.reduce(:+) == 20
        line +=  "#{frame.result[0]}\t /\t X"
      else
        line +=  "#{frame.result[0]}\t /\t #{frame.result[2]}"
      end
    else
      line += "#{result.shots[i]}\t #{result.shots[i+1]}"
    end
    line
  end
```

I'm concerned about the conditionals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea I came with: using a Hash with [Hash#default](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Hash.html#method-i-default-3D):

```
line = ""

strike = {20 => "20", 30 => "30"}
strike.default = "other"

line += strike[0]

line
#=> "other"
```

---

Did not test, but you should be able to write something like

```
def print_last_frame(result, frame, i)
  result = frame.result
  shots = result.shots

  cases = {
    strike: {20 => "X\t #{result[1]}\t /",
             30 => "X\t X\t X"},
    spare:  {20 =>"#{result[0]}\t /\t X"}

  cases[:strike].default = "X\t #{result[1]}\t #{result[2]}"
  cases[:spare].default = "#{result[0]}\t /\t #{result[2]}"
  cases.default = {}
  cases.default.default = "#{shots[i]}\t #{shots[i+1]}"

  cases[frame.value][result.sum]
end
```

Whether `frame.value` returns `:strike`, `:spare` or `nil`.

Comment: Thanks, the 1st example hashes helped me, the 2nd one did not as frame.value returns an int

Comment: Glad for it. I used `frame.value` as an example, you could define `whatever` method to return a key for the hash.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, had hard time spotting it. A-ha! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you perform your calculations as follows.

```
def last_frame(result, frame, i)
  case
  when frame.strike?
    strike(frame)
  when frame.spare?
    spare(frame)
  else
    shots(result, i)
  end
end
```

```
def strike(frame)
  case frame.result.sum
    when 30
      "X\t X\t X"
    when 20
      "X\t #{frame.result[1]}\t /"
    else
      "X\t #{frame.result[1]}\t #{frame.result[2]}"
  end
end
```

```
def spare(frame)
  case frame.result.sum
  when 20
    "#{frame.result[0]}\t /\t X"
  else
    "#{frame.result[0]}\t /\t #{frame.result[2]}"
  end
end
```

```
def shots(result, i)
  "#{result.shots[i]}\t #{result.shots[i+1]}"
end
```

Here are some arguments for organizing your calculations this way.

- breaking it into four methods makes it clear which arguments of `last_frame` are used by each case considered (`strike` and `spare` use only `frame`; `shots` uses `result` and `i`)
- breaking it into four methods facilitates testing
- there is no need for the variable `line`, initialized to an empty string then appended to (`line += ...`), as `line` is only set to a single value (i.e., there is no accumulation).
- using `puts last_frame(result, frame, i)` to print results, rather than incorporating `puts` in the method, increases the method's flexibility

I have a preference for using `case` statements rather than `if-elsif-else-end` constructs, in part because I think they look a bit neater (even when `case` has no argument, as in `last_frame`).